# Power Mock giving null when calling public static inner class method using parent class method

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

```
public abstract interface ABC extends KObject{
    public abstract XYZ addNewXYZ();
    public static final class Factory {
        public static ABC newInstance() {
            // Returns new instance for 
        }
    }
    public static abstract interface XYZ extends KObject {
        public abstract XYZ getBase();
        }
    }
}



In the calling method I am using


 clientMethod(){
    ABC  abcObj=ABC.Factory.newInstance();
    XYZ  xyz = abcObj.addNewXYZ().getBase();
    //xyz is returning null here when run junit using power mock.
}


testClientByPowermock(){ 
//tried many ways no luck

}
```

what ever the way i tried to run in power mock.

used both annotations

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(
```

can somebody help me on how to run such inner classes Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you mock and what were you expecting to receive when calling that method? It would be helpful if you could post an actual [sscce](http://sscce.org) that illustrates your problem.